# How do I assign the dictionary values so that when a key is entered as Account, it returns the value as Password in Kivy?

Tags: dictionary, kivy

**.py file**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle  
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(Widget):
    account = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

def button(self):
    print('Account Name:', self.account.text, 'Password:', self.password.text)
    self.account.text = ' '
    self.password.text = ' '

passwords = {'email1': '', 'email2': '', 'Nintendo': '', 'email3': ''}

email1 = ''
email2 = ''
email3 = ''

class pwStorer(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pwStorer().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
<MyGrid>

account: account
password: password

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    size: root.width, root.height

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2

        Label:
            text: 'Account Name:'

        TextInput:
            id: account
            multiline: False

        Label:
            text: 'Password:'

        TextInput:
            id: password
            multiline: False

    Button:
        text: 'Enter'
        on_release:
```

Essentially, when the button is released, it should return a value from the dictionary 'Passwords' that's associated to the key (or the 'account name'). How do I do it? (preferably in the .kv file). I'm fairly new to Python and have searched everywhere but cannot seem to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: In your `passwords` dictionary, just replace each occurrence of '' with a password.

Comment: I did that but I didn't want to share my passwords with you guys! The problem is actually calling trying to code the "when enter is released, obtain the value from dictionary and print it in the password.text bit on the kivy app"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `Button`, you can use:

```
    Button:
        text: 'Enter'
        on_release: password.text=app.get_password(account.text)
```

Then, in the `pwStorer`:

```
class pwStorer(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

    def get_password(self, user_name):
        try:
            pswd = passwords[user_name]
            return pswd
        except:
            return '***** No Such User****'
```

Comment: I'm getting a NameError now where passwords isn't defined, even though right above is the passwords dictionary?

Comment: Oh god I put the dictionary below where it was called, put it at the top now and it works! Thank you!